# Remove comas in String elements table and remove duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a String table with coma in some Strings: ["a", "b,c", "c,d", "d", "d", "b,a"]

My objective is to remove these comas: ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "b", "a"]

And remove duplicates (the elements order doesn't matter): ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

I have the following functions in Google App Script :

To remove the comas

```
function removeStringWithComaInTable(table) {
  for (var i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    if (table[i].includes(",")) {

      // We retrieve the string value
      var temp = [{}];
      temp = table[i].split(',');
      table[i] = temp[0];

      for (var j=1; j < temp.length; j++) {
        table.push(temp[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}
```

To remove duplicates

```
function searchUniqueDatas(table) {
  var uniqueDatas = [];

  for (var i=0; i < table.length; i++) {
    uniqueDatas = uniqueDatas.concat(table[i]);
  }
  return uniqueDatas = uniqueDatas.filter(onlyUnique);
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Both of these functions work individually. But don't work together...

```
function test() {
  var abc = [];
  abc = searchUniqueDatas(removeStringWithComaInTable(["a","b,c","c,d","d","d","b,a"]));
}
```

Th issue is that the removeStringWithComaInTable function works and send the expected result but the searchUniqueDatas function does nothing.

Maybe it's an algorithm issue. I don't see it though..

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have tried the script you shared and it does work. I have set it up like this: First the test function adding a `logger.log(abc)`. Then the `searchUniqueDatas` and then the `removeStringWithComaInTable`. It has returned the correct answer, can you share more information on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const arr = ["a", "b,c", "c,d", "d", "d", "b,a"]
const output = [];

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (el.includes(",")){
    el.split(",").forEach(split => {
      if(!output.includes(split)){
        output.push(split);
      }
    })
  } else if (!output.includes(el)) {
    output.push(el)
  }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet does the job, let me know if this is what you are looking for:

```js
const ar = ['a', 'b,c', 'c,d', 'd', 'd', 'b,a'];

const removeCommasAndDupes = ar => [
  ...new Set(ar.reduce((newAr, el) => [...newAr, ...el.split(',')], [])),
];

const newAr = removeCommasAndDupes(ar);

console.log(newAr);
```